# How to change LimitNOFILE in CoreOS at cloud-config.yaml

Tags: systemd, coreos

So far, I am only able to change the value of `ulimit -Hn` by booting CoreOS and then manually editing `/etc/systemd/system.conf` and then uncommenting the following following line and setting the value as:

```
DefaultLimitNOFILE=65536
```

How do we do the same in `cloud-config.yaml` ?

Answer (score 1):

By default there is only description about parameters you can use in your system in `/etc/systemd/system.conf` - they are all commented. So, another words, this file has no impact to CoreOS host by default.

That means we can define `/etc/systemd/system.conf` via `write_files` directive in `cloud-config.yml` with any parameters we need and it will be created on the local filesystem during host boot.

Just add the following to `cloud-config.yaml`:

```
write_files:
- path: "/etc/systemd/system.conf"
  permissions: '0644'
  owner: root
  content: |
    [Manager]
    DefaultLimitNOFILE=65536
```